# How do i make an else or if statement creating text into usrNameLabel when it does not find the website url i specified at the top

Tags: c#

So i want to display [NOT FOUND] if the web request doesnt find the url specified with strings above.

What I have done is a HWID system to identify the current user. it combines 2 strings to find my github repository and in that repository a file titled with their hwid and it displays their user name inside.
I want to make it so that if it does not find that file/website url/git repository that it displays Not Found.

Everything was defined before hand / everything works how it should but if it does not find the
url it will just crash.

or if it gets removed.
also this will happen if it does not find a connection to the internet.
but i have a fix for that which will switch the text to Not Connected when the check for Online/Offline status comes back as Offline.

i have read some on else statements and as far as i know it needs an if statement above.
i dont have one there because my code did not require one before.

Can someone please help me rewrite it?

code:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            HWID = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.Value; 
            textBox1.Text = HWID;
            //downloads the username of the user
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            string GithubRepository = "INSERT GITHUB LINK";
            string GithubRepositoryImg = "INSERT OTHER GITHUB LINK";
            string urlEndInPNG = ".png";
            String strPageCode = client.DownloadString(GithubRepository+=HWID);

            string strProfPicUrl = GithubRepositoryImg += HWID += urlEndInPNG;
            
            usrNameLabel.Text = strPageCode;
// Insert else or if statement that says it to display "[NOT FOUND]" when it doesnt find it.

//my try
else{
            usrNameLabel.Text = "Not Found";
}
```

What it displays when it finds the url
[Image of what it displays](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7uHc5.png)

I have googled how to create one but it does not work pls help.
thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a try-catch more than an if/else statement.

Try as following:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HWID = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User.Value;
        textBox1.Text = HWID;
        //downloads the username of the user
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        string GithubRepository = "INSERT GITHUB LINK";
        string GithubRepositoryImg = "INSERT OTHER GITHUB LINK";
        string urlEndInPNG = ".png";

        string strPageCode = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            strPageCode = client.DownloadString(GithubRepository += HWID);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            usrNameLabel.Text = "Not Found";
        }

        string strProfPicUrl = GithubRepositoryImg += HWID += urlEndInPNG;

        usrNameLabel.Text = string.IsNullOrEmpty(strPageCode) ? usrNameLabel.Text : strPageCode;
    }
```

When the code throws the exception, label's text will be set to "Not Found", in case it doesn't find the repository you're searching for.

Comment: thank you this has worked for me :D I'm new to c# so I don't know how it works that much yet.